# JQuery Mobile login form for remote service (without server side access)

Tags: jquery-mobile, authentication

I'm trying to create a mobile version of a service we have running at our University. The problem is that I don't have any server side access. All I have is the authorization from the University to access the service if I find out how. I created the interface in JQuery Mobile but for now it doesn't do anything other then navigating dummy data. My main problem is the login form at this point and this is the code:

```
    <body>
    <div data-role="page" id="login">
        <div data-role="header" data-theme="e">
            <h1>MobileApp</h1>
        </div>  

<div class="ui-body ui-body-c">
        <div data-role="content">
            <form method="post" rel="external" action="https://somedomain.com/passwordcheck">
                <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
                    <li data-role="list-divider">Login</li>
                    <li data-role="fieldcontain" class="ui-hide-label">
                        <label for="name">User:</label>
                        <input id="username" class="inputB" type="text" name="x_username">
                    </li>

                    <li data-role="fieldcontain" class="ui-hide-label">
                        <label for="name">Password:</label>
                        <input id="password" class="inputB" type="text" name="x_password">
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div><button type="submit" value="Login" data-theme="b">Login</button></div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

As you can see i post the User and Password data to "https://somedomain.com/passwordcheck" and if the data are correct it redirects me to the "https://somedomain.com/index" page of the service. But this is not what I want. What I want is the passwordcheck to occur as it does but to open my own mobile #index page. I understand that I'm handling this all wrong the way it is now but I cannot seem to find the right way to do it.

I think I need to find a way to capture the passwordcheck response and then handle it somehow (open #index if the login is correct or something else if it's not) while not opening, or at least hiding the original web page. Any help is really appreciated.